# SELECT WHERE column1 = 1 AND column2 = MAX(column2)

Tags: c#, sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I have table like this

```
|Column 1 |Column 2|Column 3|
|        1|       1|       1|
|        2|       1|       2|
|        3|       1|       3|
|        4|       2|       1|
|        5|       1|       4|
|        6|       2|       2|
|        7|       2|       3|
|        8|       2|       4|
|        9|       2|       5|
```

Now what i want to do is to select `Column 1, Column 2, Column 3` WHERE Column2 = 1 AND Column 3 is largest for column 2 (`4`)

Comment: can you use window functions?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: One option is to use a subquery `where Column3 = (select Max(Column3) from table)`

Comment: I am new so my questions are stupid but:

@vkp What do you mean by that? I am using VS Windowed form app

GurwinderSingh What is RDBMS?

Comment: RDBMS is Relational DataBase Management System.  Basically what type of Database are you using, SQL Server, MySql, Oracle, ect.

Comment: I am using Firebird 3.0

@Juharr your solution is ok (+ where column2 = 1) but for some reason it gives me -104 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window function `rank` to find the max of col3

```
select col1, col2, col3 from
    (select 
        col1, col2, col3,
        rank() over (order by col3 desc nulls last) rnk
    from my_table
    where col2 = 1)
where rnk = 1;
```

or do this, if that is not supported, but careful, you have to handle if `nulls` are there in col3:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from my_table t
where col2 = 1
and col3 = (select max(col3)
    from my_table
    where col2 = t.col2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do it like that but in second where statement i was using only select and where but forgot to write FROM. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Column1,
       Column2,  
       MAX( Column3 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Column2 ) AS Column3
  FROM Table
 WHERE Column2 = 1;
```

In the above soln, I am extracting max value in the group Column2=1 by using Window functions and WHERE condition. With the help of window functions you can get the max/min/count without using any GROUP BY clause on any specific column.

Comment: gon' be duplicates

Comment: What does it mean?